# What is best tag for "spot the mistake" questions?

Tags: discussion, tagging, solution-verification

Occasionally we get a question of the form: "Look at this derivation/computation. Clearly, the result is wrong. Where is the mistake?"

It is slightly different from typical [solution-verification](/questions/tagged/solution-verification) question. Namely here the OP *knows* that the solution is incorrect, so strictly speaking they do not ask to *check* their proof but to *find* a mistake.

Would [solution-verification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification) or [proof-verification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-verification) be still a reasonable choice for this type of questions? Or is [fake-proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fake-proofs) better?

Or (most likely) is this something which has to be judged on case-by-case bases?

**EDIT:** Of course, neither of the above tags is supposed to stand on its own. So the question is supposed to be what tags should be added in addition to the tags identifying area of mathematics from which the question is.

Comment: Yet another option is to simply use a tag relevant to the topic of the question. For example, if the question about spotting the weak link in an argument that contradicts a known result of general topology or Galois theory, then I would just tag the question with [tag:general-topology] or [tag:galois-theory]. All depending on the type of mistake. If the error is, for example, about a misconception of rules (or lack thereof) of complex multivalued roots, then I wold add the tag [tag:fake-proofs], and look for an appropriate duplicate.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I thought it goes without saying that those tags should not stand on their own. But I edited the post to clarify this.

Comment: Yes, that was clear @Martin. My point was that IMO in some cases no extra tag is necessary. Sorry about not making that clear.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That might be a reasonable option. So if you wish, perhaps you could post your comment as an answer. (Perhaps with stressing a bit more that you meant using *none* of the above tags - as you see, I was still able to misunderstood your comment.) Of course, if you wish to, you can delete some of the comments here, if you think clean-up might be useful. And if you have time, you can have a look [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2016/11/25) on the choice of tags for the question which prompted me to ask this.